# Responsive Size Font Awesome Icons

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, icons, font-awesome

I'm using `FontAwesome` icons in my responsive `Bootstrap` website and want to display icons at different sizes depending on the screen resolution.

Ideally I'd like to display the font awesome icons using a percentage of the containers width, i.e. 50% of the width, so they scale up and down.  I know that I could probably do this just using svg icons, but I wanted to use `FontAwesome`, as I'm using it elsewhere in my site.

I understand you can specify the size using classes, i.e. fa-lg or fa-2x.  Would the best solution be to use `Bootstrap` classes to hide and display the various sizes depending on screen resolution, or can you get the icons to scale automatically using percentage?

Answer (score 21):

You HAVE TO see this answer:

[Font scaling based on width of container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container/19814948#19814948)

Use "vw" units on font-size. Also check browser support table which is mentioned there - its pretty good.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the best way is define CSS giving the glyphicon a font-size to your liking:

```
.glyphicon-small {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.glyphicon-medium {
    font-size: 2em;
}

.glyphicon-big {
    font-size: 4em;
}
```

But, if you want to adapt it by screen size, you can have just one CSS class and modify it during execution with [CSS @media rule](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) to get desired results:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 299px) {
    .glyphicon {
        font-size: 1.2em;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 799px) {
    .glyphicon {
        font-size: 2em;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    .glyphicon {
        font-size: 4em;
    }
}
```

This will clean your code and you will have really nice results with minimum coding effort ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
/* Font ico (Font-Awesome) */
.elastic-fai-xl{
    font-size:80px;
}
.elastic-fai-lg{
    font-size:50px;
}
.elastic-fai-md{
    font-size:40px;
}
.elastic-fai-sm{
    font-size:30px;
}
.elastic-fai-xs{
    font-size:20px;
}
/* Extra small devices */
@media(max-width:544px){
    .elastic-fai-group > .elastic-fai, .elastic-fai-xs{
        font-size:20px;
    }
}
/* Small devices */
@media(min-width:544px){
    .elastic-fai-group > .elastic-fai, .elastic-fai-sm{
        font-size:30px;
    }
}
/* Medium devices */
@media(min-width:768px){
    .elastic-fai-group > .elastic-fai, .elastic-fai-md{
        font-size:40px;
    }
}
/* Large devices */
@media(min-width:992px){
    .elastic-fai-group > .elastic-fai, .elastic-fai-lg{
        font-size:50px;
    }
}
/* Exrta Large devices */
@media(min-width:1200px){
    .elastic-fai-group > .elastic-fai, .elastic-fai-xl{
        font-size:80px;
    }
}
```